# selectionChanged is not called when text is selected in a QWebView C# 

Tags: qt, qwebview, selectionchanged

I'm having a QWebView in my windows that contains text. I want the selected word (or words it doesn't matter) to be written somewhere else, but the signal selectionChanged is never called. Do I need to set something before? For now, all I have is a slot waiting be called...I don't even do something for now because the signal is never sent

thanks!

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->setupUi();
    connect(m_WebView, SIGNAL(selectionChanged()), this, SLOT(newSelection()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::setupUi()
{
    m_WebView = new QWebView();
    m_LineEdit = new QLineEdit();

    QVBoxLayout* lay = new QVBoxLayout();

    lay->addWidget(m_LineEdit);
    lay->addWidget(m_WebView);

    QWidget* wid = new QWidget(this);
    wid->setLayout(lay);

    setCentralWidget(wid);
}

void MainWindow::newSelection()
{
    m_LineEdit->setText(m_WebView->selectedText());
}
```

Comment: I made a little projet just to show what I want to do...anything else was not necessary!

Comment: Unless I'm reading your example wrong, it looks very similar to mine in python and mine works...not sure...

Comment: yeah it looks like...I don't know python...but it doesn't work in my projet

Comment: Well I think the point is that I am not setting any attributes on the WebView or anything special, other than just directly connecting the signal to a method. Have you tried printing as opposed to setting the value on the line edit to make sure its hitting your newSelection() method?

Comment: This was a [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44252) in Qt 4.6 (I think, since Qt 4.7 was release 1 month after the patch was applied). Or you forgot to use the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the example you gave didn't work.  This works (and it is because I am connection to the page not the view).  I'd actually consider filing a bug report with the devs if I were you.  From the [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebview.html#selectionChanged), it seems like this SHOULD work.

cpp:

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QWebView>
    #include <QLineEdit>
    #include <QVBoxLayout>
    #include <QTimer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->setupUi();
    connect(m_WebView->page(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged()), this, SLOT(newSelection()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::setupUi()
{
    m_WebView = new QWebView();
    m_WebView->load(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com/"));
    m_WebView->show();
    m_LineEdit = new QLineEdit();

    QVBoxLayout* lay = new QVBoxLayout();

    lay->addWidget(m_LineEdit);
    lay->addWidget(m_WebView);


    QWidget* wid = new QWidget(this);
    wid->setLayout(lay);

    setCentralWidget(wid);
}

void MainWindow::newSelection()
{
    m_LineEdit->setText(m_WebView->selectedText());
}
```

h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class QWebView;
class QLineEdit;
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void setupUi();

  protected slots:
    void newSelection();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWebView * m_WebView;
    QLineEdit * m_LineEdit;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: I don't understand why...but your code works...kinda weird...but at least it works! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your code looks like, but here is a PyQt fully working example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.resize(800,600)

        self.web = QtWebKit.QWebView()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.web)

        self.web.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"))
        self.web.selectionChanged.connect(self.selectionChanged)

    def selectionChanged(self):
        print self.web.selectedText()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.show()
    dialog.raise_()
    app.exec_()
```

The `selectionChanged` signal is emitted just fine and calls the designated slot, when I select text on the webpage. Not sure what you could be doing wrong. Provide some code, and enjoy this freebie.